# Error scale x numeric

Tags: r

I have a set of data that looks like this, in the fisier.txt file:

```
Simbol  GIG RC  RF  RE  RS  Rata_autonomie_fin  RAC RAI RSTO    RIG FMCP    SPART   AC1000  RRAC
RAF 0,89    2,37    51,99   0,06    1,12    8,36    98,36   1,64    36,86   8,36    9,36    0,11    419,7634869 6,357274319
BIH 0,63    4,11    13,75   0,05    1,60    1,66    79,83   20,17   35,92   1,66    2,66    0,38    633,2949456 1,579043078
REK 0,37    17,58   26,93   0,17    2,67    0,60    62,46   37,54   21,71   0,60    1,60    0,63    651,1769514 1,53568089
SIR 0,83    3,60    43,79   0,07    1,20    5,60    85,35   14,65   33,87   5,60    6,73    0,15    471,9731625 2,118764539
CFS 0,73    3,02    22,48   0,06    1,37    2,72    81,82   18,18   27,03   2,72    3,72    0,27    408,9188168 2,445473182
MUS 0,48    11,63   22,45   0,12    2,10    0,92    55,75   44,25   40,99   0,92    1,93    0,52    556,4278398 1,79717823
SOM 0,13    7,64    13,19   0,11    7,62    0,16    44,67   55,33   6,01    0,16    1,19    0,84    308,2362465 3,244264785
GAR 0,68    0,25    1,45    0,00    1,47    2,15    61,66   38,34   32,39   2,15    3,15    0,32    340,2708811 2,938835074
DEN 0,65    5,81    25,07   0,09    1,53    1,87    63,15   36,85   45,57   1,87    2,86    0,35    419,4486125 2,38408227
```

I try to run the code below and I get this error:
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

```
firme<-read.table("fisier_firme",header=TRUE)
firme
nume_obs<-firme[1]
nume_obs
date_std<-scale(firme[2:14], scale=TRUE)
#here is where the error occurs
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Comment: In your location, does R think the decimal separator is `.` instead of `,`? If so, your numeric columns are actually being read in as character columns (check by running `str(firme)`). To change this behavior, you can add the argument `dec=","` in `read.table`. Also, you don't need to break up your data frame into separate objects. You can do `firm[,2:ncol(firme)] = scale(firme[, 2:ncol(firme)])`.

Comment: Thank you!I added dec="," and it is working now.

Comment: I noticed that you haven't accepted the answers to any of your other questions. If an answer solves your problem, please take a moment to click the "accept" check mark in the upper left corner of the answer. This lets others know that the question has an accepted solution.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know how, but now I do!